# How to read last 5 line of txt file in php which start and end with #

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have txt file in which i want to read last 5 line Whih start with # and end with #.
txt file look like this;

```
#STA:00008;TM:04/30/2016,17:56:03;C:02;V:0.02;AD15:00000;AD16:00000;AD17:00000;AD18:00000;DI:001110;DO:0000;#
#STA:00008;TM:04/30/2016,17:56:32;C:03;V:0.02;AD15:00000;AD16:00000;AD17:00000;AD18:00000;DI:001110;DO:0000;#
#STA:00008;TM:04/30/2016,17:57:02;C:04;V:0.02;AD15:00000;AD16:00000;AD17:00000;AD18:00000;DI:001110;DO:0000;#
```

**From comments:**

```
$file = file_get_contents("F:\RTU GSM\S220 GSM GPRS Remote Controller PC Configurator V2.1\profile\severtxt.txt");
$station = explode(";TM:",$file);
$keywords = preg_split("/;+/", $file);
print_r($keywords);
```

Comment: That is easy and doesn't even require regex, where are you stuck?

Comment: $file = file_get_contents("F:\RTU GSM\S220 GSM GPRS Remote Controller PC Configurator V2.1\profile\severtxt.txt");


$station= explode(";TM:",$file);
$keywords = preg_split("/;+/", $file);
print_r($keywords);

Answer (score 0):

Several methods, one being the following:

```
$file = @file("your_file_here.txt");
$i = count($file);
for ($j=$i-5;$j<$i;$j++) {
    $columns = explode(';', $file[$j]);
    print_r($columns);
}
```

Comment: I want to split this line from # to # in a single array